# How can I merge these two functions into a single one ? [python 3.]

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, opencv, mouse

It has been several weeks since I started learning python (via anaconda). I have started to develop my personal code for some applications for my work.
So the question is the next one, I have this two function `draw_rectangle` and `magnification` which each one uses a different `mouse_handler`. 
As you can see in the code, both functions are the same, so what I want to do is to merge them into just one function (trying to make a better code structure).

Finally, I call these functions in another script via:

```
data['image_right'], rectangle['right'] = draw_rectangle(data['image_right'])

magnification = magnification(data['image_left'])
```

Here are the functions :

```
def mouse_handler(action, x, y, flags,img) :
    # Action to be taken when left mouse button is pressed
    if action==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        rectangle.append([x,y])
    # Action to be taken when left mouse button is released
    elif action==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        rectangle.append([x,y])

def draw_rectangle(img):
    global rectangle
    rectangle = []
    #Create the window to show image
    cv2.namedWindow("Image",cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)  
    cv2.setMouseCallback("Image", mouse_handler, img)
    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()    
    img = img[rectangle[0][1]:rectangle[1][1],rectangle[0][0]:rectangle[1][0]]

    return img, rectangle


def mouse_handler2(action, x, y, flags,img) :
    # Action to be taken when left mouse button is pressed
    if action==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        coordinates.append([x,y])
    # Action to be taken when left mouse button is released
    elif action==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        coordinates.append([x,y])

def magnification(img):
     global coordinates
     coordinates = []
     imgcopy = img.copy()
     #Create the window to show image
     cv2.namedWindow("Image",cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
     cv2.setMouseCallback("Image", mouse_handler2, imgcopy)
     cv2.putText(imgcopy, "Click/unclick", (int(imgcopy.shape[1]/4), int(imgcopy.shape[0]/2)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 3, (0, 0, 0), 3)
     cv2.imshow("Image", imgcopy)
     cv2.waitKey(0)
     cv2.destroyAllWindows()

     magnification = 10/np.sqrt( np.power((coordinates[0][1]-coordinates[1][1]),2)+ np.power((coordinates[0][0]-coordinates[1][0]),2))

     return magnification
```

Comment: So basically you want is to create a new function for selecting a rectangle that can be used by both of the functions?

Comment: More than creating the rectangle, I'm interested in the coordinates.

Comment: i want to mention that your functions are not self-contained, as you are manipulating globals, namely 'coordinates' in both of them. I highly recommend make these into function-arguments, then also your problem will be stated more clearly

Comment: That is what i'm trying to do, but since mouse_handler is not called as a function (or not as a normal function) because i dont place arguments when calling it, still it does get the image to work with.
Hence, i don't know how to make them self-contained. That is the big question i have.